# Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS Enablement Stack has unmet mesa-dev dependencies

Tags: 14.04, dependencies, lts, mesa

I have just updated to the latest LTS Enablement Stack for Ubuntu 14.04.4 using the wiki.
I am trying to install some dependencies for building plexhometheater and getting an error.

Any ideas what the issue could be? Why are these libraries not provided by the installed libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-wily and libgles2-mesa-dev-lts-wily packages.

```
sudo apt-get -s install libgl1-mesa-dev libgles2-mesa-dev
...
...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgl1-mesa-dev : Depends: mesa-common-dev (= 10.3.0-0ubuntu2intel1)
libgles2-mesa-dev : Depends: libgles2-mesa (= 10.3.0-0ubuntu2intel1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


dpkg -l | grep mesa
ii  libegl1-mesa-dev-lts-wily:amd64           11.0.2-1ubuntu4~trusty1                       amd64        free implementation of the EGL API -- development files
ii  libegl1-mesa-lts-wily:amd64               11.0.2-1ubuntu4~trusty1                       amd64        free implementation of the EGL API -- runtime
ii  libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-wily:amd64            11.0.2-1ubuntu4~trusty1                       amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX development files
ii  libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-wily:amd64            11.0.2-1ubuntu4~trusty1                       amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
ii  libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-wily:amd64            11.0.2-1ubuntu4~trusty1                       amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX runtime
ii  libglapi-mesa-lts-wily:amd64              11.0.2-1ubuntu4~trusty1                       amd64        free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
ii  libgles1-mesa-lts-wily:amd64              11.0.2-1ubuntu4~trusty1                       amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL|ES 1.x API -- runtime
ii  libgles2-mesa-dev-lts-wily:amd64          11.0.2-1ubuntu4~trusty1                       amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL|ES 2.x API -- development files
ii  libgles2-mesa-lts-wily:amd64              11.0.2-1ubuntu4~trusty1                       amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL|ES 2.x API -- runtime
ii  libglu1-mesa:amd64                        9.0.0-2                                       amd64        Mesa OpenGL utility library (GLU)
ii  libglu1-mesa-dev                          9.0.0-2                                       amd64        Mesa OpenGL utility library -- development files
ii  libmirclientplatform-mesa:amd64           0.1.8+14.04.20140411-0ubuntu1                 amd64        Display server for Ubuntu - client platform library for Mesa
ii  libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-wily:amd64       11.0.2-1ubuntu4~trusty1                       amd64        implementation of the Wayland EGL platform -- runtime
ii  mesa-common-dev-lts-wily:amd64            11.0.2-1ubuntu4~trusty1                       amd64        Developer documentation for Mesa
ii  mesa-utils                                8.1.0-2                                       amd64        Miscellaneous Mesa GL utilities

dpkg -l | grep xorg
ii  python3-xkit                              0.5.0ubuntu2                                  all          library for the manipulation of xorg.conf files (Python 3)
ii  xorg                                      1:7.7+1ubuntu8.1                              amd64        X.Org X Window System
ii  xorg-docs-core                            1:1.7-1                                       all          Core documentation for the X.org X Window System
ii  xorg-sgml-doctools                        1:1.11-1                                      all          Common tools for building X.Org SGML documentation
ii  xserver-xorg-core-lts-wily                2:1.17.2-1ubuntu9.1~trusty1                   amd64        Xorg X server - core server
ii  xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-wily           1:7.7+7ubuntu4~trusty1                        amd64        X.Org X server -- input driver metapackage
ii  xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-wily         1:2.9.2-1ubuntu1~trusty2                      amd64        X.Org X server -- evdev input driver
ii  xserver-xorg-input-mouse-lts-wily         1:1.9.1-1~trusty1                             amd64        X.Org X server -- mouse input driver
ii  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-wily     1.8.2-1ubuntu1~trusty1                        amd64        Synaptics TouchPad driver for X.Org server
ii  xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse-lts-wily       1:13.1.0-0ubuntu1~trusty1                     amd64        X.Org X server -- VMMouse input driver to use with VMWare
ii  xserver-xorg-input-wacom-lts-wily         1:0.30.0-0ubuntu3~trusty1                     amd64        X.Org X server -- Wacom input driver
ii  xserver-xorg-lts-wily                     1:7.7+7ubuntu4~trusty1                        amd64        X.Org X server
ii  xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-wily           1:7.7+7ubuntu4~trusty1                        amd64        X.Org X server -- output driver metapackage
ii  xserver-xorg-video-ati-lts-wily           1:7.5.0+git20150819-0ubuntu1~trusty1          amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI display driver wrapper
ii  xserver-xorg-video-cirrus-lts-wily        1:1.5.3-1ubuntu1~trusty1                      amd64        X.Org X server -- Cirrus display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-lts-wily         1:0.4.4-1build3~trusty1                       amd64        X.Org X server -- fbdev display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-wily         2:2.99.917+git20150808-0ubuntu4~trusty2       amd64        X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-mach64-lts-wily        6.9.5-1~trusty1                               amd64        X.Org X server -- ATI Mach64 display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-mga-lts-wily           1:1.6.4-1~trusty1                             amd64        X.Org X server -- MGA display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-neomagic-lts-wily      1:1.2.9-1~trusty1                             amd64        X.Org X server -- Neomagic display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-lts-wily       1:1.0.11-1ubuntu3~trusty1                     amd64        X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-openchrome-lts-wily    1:0.3.3-1ubuntu1~trusty1                      amd64        X.Org X server -- VIA display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-qxl-lts-wily           0.1.4-3ubuntu1~trusty1                        amd64        X.Org X server -- QXL display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-r128-lts-wily          6.10.0-1~trusty1                              amd64        X.Org X server -- ATI r128 display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-radeon-lts-wily        1:7.5.0+git20150819-0ubuntu1~trusty1          amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI Radeon display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-savage-lts-wily        1:2.3.8-1ubuntu1~trusty1                      amd64        X.Org X server -- Savage display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion-lts-wily 1:1.7.8-1ubuntu4~trusty1                      amd64        X.Org X server -- SiliconMotion display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb-lts-wily        1:0.9.6-2build3~trusty1                       amd64        X.Org X server -- SiS USB display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-tdfx-lts-wily          1:1.4.6-1~trusty1                             amd64        X.Org X server -- tdfx display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-trident-lts-wily       1:1.3.7-1~trusty1                             amd64        X.Org X server -- Trident display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-vesa-lts-wily          1:2.3.4-0ubuntu1~trusty1                      amd64        X.Org X server -- VESA display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-vmware-lts-wily        1:13.1.0-0ubuntu1build2~trusty1               amd64        X.Org X server -- VMware display driver

dpkg -l | grep intel
ii  i965-va-driver:amd64                      1.4.0-0intel1                                 amd64        VAAPI driver for Intel G45 & HD Graphics family
ii  intel-gpu-tools                           1.8-1                                         amd64        tools for debugging the Intel graphics driver
ii  libdrm-intel1:amd64                       2.4.64-1~ubuntu14.04.1                        amd64        Userspace interface to intel-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libva-dev:amd64                           1.4.0-0intel1                                 amd64        Video Acceleration (VA) API for Linux -- development files
ii  libva-drm1:amd64                          1.4.0-0intel1                                 amd64        Video Acceleration (VA) API for Linux -- DRM runtime
ii  libva-egl1:amd64                          1.4.0-0intel1                                 amd64        Video Acceleration (VA) API for Linux -- EGL runtime
ii  libva-glx1:amd64                          1.4.0-0intel1                                 amd64        Video Acceleration (VA) API for Linux -- GLX runtime
ii  libva-intel-vaapi-driver                  1.3.0-1ubuntu1                                all          VAAPI driver for Intel G45 & HD Graphics family (transitional package)
ii  libva-tpi1:amd64                          1.4.0-0intel1                                 amd64        Video Acceleration (VA) API for Linux -- TPI runtime
ii  libva-wayland1:amd64                      1.4.0-0intel1                                 amd64        Video Acceleration (VA) API for Linux -- Wayland runtime
ii  libva-x11-1:amd64                         1.4.0-0intel1                                 amd64        Video Acceleration (VA) API for Linux -- X11 runtime
ii  libva1:amd64                              1.4.0-0intel1                                 amd64        Video Acceleration (VA) API for Linux -- runtime
ii  va-driver-all:amd64                       1.4.0-0intel1                                 amd64        Video Acceleration (VA) API -- driver metapackage
ii  vainfo                                    1.4.0-0intel1                                 amd64        Video Acceleration (VA) API for Linux -- info program
ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-wily         2:2.99.917+git20150808-0ubuntu4~trusty2       amd64        X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `wily` stack, you should install `wily` packages

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-wily libgles2-mesa-dev-lts-wily
```

These packages are alternatives to `libgl1-mesa-dev` and `libgles2-mesa-dev`.

Comment: The wily packages are already installed: `libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-wily is already the newest version.
libgles2-mesa-dev-lts-wily is already the newest version.` Are they a complete replacement for libgl1-mesa-dev and libgles2-mesa-dev?

Comment: So there is no need to install `libgl1-mesa-dev` and `libgles2-mesa-dev`. They won't install either way and it is correct. You can't install packages from another stack.

Comment: Yes, they are a complete replacement.